# rendering textures with integer internal format

Tags: opengl, pygame, textures, pyopengl

I wish to create and operate textures with integer internal format (for further interop with opencl). However it seems I've missed something important in question of mapping this texture. Here is a code sample that will say a lot more. Internal format could be switched by defining INTERNAL and DATACOPY variables.

It works pretty fine if I use float normalized internal format (GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA) for texture. The sample code will draw noisy coloured image. But once I switched to (GL_RGBA8UI, GL_RGBA_INTEGER) window becomes black.

Probably problem is only with my configuration (nvidia fermi-arch). So any help in pointing to root of my problems is appreciated.

```
    import pygame
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    import os

    XLEN, YLEN = 320, 200

    INTERNAL, DATACOPY = GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA
    #INTERNAL, DATACOPY = GL_RGBA8UI, GL_RGBA_INTEGER


    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((XLEN, YLEN), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL, 24)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, XLEN, YLEN, 0, -1, 1)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    tex = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, INTERNAL, 256, 256, 0, DATACOPY, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, os.urandom(4 * XLEN * YLEN))
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

    running = True
    while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                            running = False

            glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

            glBegin(GL_QUADS)

            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
            glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0)

            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
            glVertex2f(XLEN, 0.0)

            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0)
            glVertex2f(XLEN, YLEN)

            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
            glVertex2f(0.0, YLEN)

            glEnd()

            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

            pygame.display.flip()

    glDeleteTextures(tex)

    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your shader? You can't use integral textures without a shader. You probably got an OpenGL error somewhere.

Comment: I'm planning to generate texture using opencl kernel. But was testing before a bit. Is it possible to upload texture data from host memory? Or it could only be generated using shaders?

Comment: @reddot: You can create an integral texture without shaders. But you cannot _access_ it (render with it) without shaders. The fixed-function pipeline has no facilities for performing operations on integral textures. How you create it doesn't matter; but if you want to actually do something with it, you need shaders.